# mysql row count not matching with the total COUNT

Tags: mysql

My total rows showing me `253` but the original rows are `267`. I tried online and cannot seem to find answer to this. What is going on here.

[image]

Comment: how do you know if the row is 267? last id increment is different than row count

Comment: I have double-checked, every original id is matching with the `student_FK`

Comment: then... so what?  last `student_FK ` id  is different than row count

Answer (score 0):

FIXED. My bad!

All the rows are inserted through excel.

The original `level_FK` column sql type is to accpet only `int` and some rows in excel had alphabets and because of that, only the inters are send and left the alphabets. after replacing all the alphabets with `int`. It worked.